# Minimum permissions for executing ALTER USER WITH LOGIN

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, what are the permissions required to run the following command

ALTER USER [John Doe] WITH LOGIN = [John Doe]

I am trying to create an user with minimal permissions and the above command needs to be executed by the user.

Thanks

Comment: Not really a programming question. This is probably better suited to [dba.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: You could create a stored procedure with the execute as user and grant execute on that stored procedure to the minimal user

Comment: You can see permission set on the [documentation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)

> To change the name of a user requires the ALTER ANY USER permission.
>
> To change the user name, target login, or SID of a user having CONTROL
>   permission on the database requires the CONTROL permission on the
>   database.
>
> To change the default schema or language requires ALTER permission on
>   the user. Users can change only their own default schema or language.

From that, I get that alter permissions on the user are needed generally (which ALTER ANY USER subsumes).